# Group panda values by unique values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, binning

I have the following panda dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'trial_time': ['0', '0',
                              '1', '1'],
                   'Max Speed': [1., 2, 3, 4]})
```

I want to create a dataframe that would for each unique value in trial_time bin/grab the corresponding values in an array. So
0 -> [1,2]
1 -> [3,4]

I read through pandas groupby documentation, but I'm still a bit stuck...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```
s = df.groupby('trial_time')['Max Speed'].apply(lambda x: list(x))
print(s)

trial_time
0    [1.0, 2.0]
1    [3.0, 4.0]
Name: Max Speed, dtype: object
```

So, this will return a `pd.Series` with the unique values from `trial_time` as the index, and the corresponding lists as data.